# pagination max-size is not working in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i am using Angular 1.3.I have a pagination thats working fine but if have 5000 values my pagination numbers are increasing.Even though i have given max-size="3" but its not working.i can show all numbers in my page.Here i don't know what is my issue?

```
            <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"  
                 max-size="3" boundary-links="true"  
                 items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-sm">  
            </pagination>
```

Comment: Acc to documentation your correct..can u give us a plunker with this issue

Comment: hi Chowdary.   http://plnkr.co/edit/tYU7IJAMu4zxHhvEzEkN?p=preview

Comment: @Vivekvetrri your plnkr was not showing pagination. The issue is that `pagination` directive is deprecated. You should use [`uib-pagination`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#pagination) directive to render paging. Is this the issue you were trying to resolve?

Comment: @Vivekvetrri here is the [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3EXbIflViOoVOcskQNhQ?p=preview). Is this something you tried to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @ Stanislav Kvitash.Its working fine :-)